# Java: ZonedDateTime - parse timestring without timezone

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have a datetime-string WITHOUT a specified timezone.
But I want to parse it with ZonedDateTime to give it a timezone-meaning in the act of parsing.

This code is working but uses LocalDateTime for parsing - and then convert it to ZonedDateTime with giving it a timezone-meaning.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ("yyyyMMddHHmm");

String tmstr = "201810110907";

LocalDateTime tmp = LocalDateTime.parse (tnstr,dtf);
ZonedDateTime mytime = ZonedDateTime.of (tmp, ZoneId.of ("UTC"));
```

Is there a way I can parse it directly with ZonedDateTime?

I have tried this, but it was not working.

```
mytime = mytime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).parse(str,dtf);
```

Comment: You already know the format... what's stopping you for just appending a string with the correct timezone you want to the raw date string?

Comment: By the way, I suggest educating the publisher of your data about the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The format seen in your Question is close to complying with the “Basic” variation in the standard format for a date-with-time. To fully comply, insert a `T` between the date portion and the time-of-day portion: `"20181011T0907"`. Even better used the expanded variation, also used by default in the *java.time* classes: `"2018-10-11T09:07"`. And if the date with time was intended to be regarded as in UTC, then say so by appending a `Z` on the end: `"2018-10-11T09:07Z"`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may specify a default time zone on the formatter:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmm")
            .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    String tmstr = "201810110907";
    ZonedDateTime mytime = ZonedDateTime.parse(tmstr, dtf);
    System.out.println(mytime);
```

Output:

> 2018-10-11T09:07Z[UTC]

Bonus tip: Rather than `ZoneId.of("UTC")` it’s usually nicer to use `ZoneOffset.UTC`. If you accept the output being printed as `2018-10-11T09:07Z` instead (`Z` meaning UTC).

Comment: This doesn't work as soon as I make `HHmm` optional and don't supply a time it in the string. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Then you need to use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and use its `parseDefaulting` method for specifying which time of day you want if it's not in the string. There are some examples out there, please search.